# exponential function with polynomial exponent

Tags: integration, exponential-function

hi guys can anyone help me, I am currently working with some integrals and i am tangled with $$\int_0^1 x^2(1-x)e^{-ax^2+b(1-x)^2}dx$$ and $$\int_0^\infty x^{-1}e^{-ax^2-bx^{-2}}dx$$ I had tried completing the square and substitution

Answer (score 1):

Set $t=a-b$. Then your integral is
$$
\int_0^1 x^2(1-x)e^{-ax^2+b(1-x)^2}dx=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^1 dx\ e^{-t x^2-2 b x+b}+\frac{e^{b}}{8}\frac{\partial^3}{\partial b^3}\int_0^1 dx\ e^{-t x^2-2 b x}\ ,
$$
evaluated at $t=a-b$ at the end of the calculation. Then complete the square and use the definition of the error function (Erf) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

The final result is (assuming $a>b$)
$$
\frac{1}{{4 (a-b)^{7/2}}}e^{-a} \left(\sqrt{\pi } \left((2 b+3) b (a-b)+(a-b)^2+2 b^3\right) e^{\frac{a^2}{a-b}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a-b}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a-b}}\right)\right)+2 \sqrt{a-b} \left(-(a b+a-b) e^{a+b}+a+b^2-b\right)\right)\ .
$$

Comment: I am lost with what you dis sir, can you refer any reference of the technique that you use?

Comment: I just used the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-t x^2}=-x^2 e^{-t x^2}$. So by a suitable number of differentiations of an exponential, you can bring 'downstairs' as many powers of $x$ as you wish. Then, the truncated integral of a Gaussian gives an error function (nothing more elementary than that)...but feel free to ask more if you need more hints

Comment: Thank you so much sir, how about the secone one sir?  I Already tried to substitute $/frac{1}{x^2}$ but i think the integrand becomes complecated.

Comment: @acm Your second integral does not admit an elementary antiderivative. If you change variable $x^2=t$, you obtain $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty dt\frac{1}{t}e^{-a t-b/t}dt $$, which you should be able to massage a bit to get to this form http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678483/integral-representation-of-bessel-function-k-vy-frac12-int-0-inft ...the final result is $K_0(2\sqrt{ab})$, in terms of a Bessel function (assuming of course $a>0,b>0$).

Comment: sir does the my first integral needs to be integrated with respect to b and t? and I forgot that a,b>0

Comment: thank you so much sir for your help....